# SKShapeNode coordinates seem reversed when using UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uipangesturerecognizer, coordinate-systems

I've run into a problem with swift when creating a SKShapeNode where it seems as though my 'y' coordinate is inverted.

Initially I place my node at the bottom of the screen and added a physics body (which is placed correctly given that I've turned set skView.showsPhysics to true and verified this) but whenever i try to interact with the node with UIPanGestureRecognizer it will not move unless I interact with the very upper, opposite side of the screen. I've found that it will react no matter where the node is, but i must invert the Y location of my input.

Furthermore if i drag downward on the inverted location, the node will move downward, so in some sense it is not completely inverted in that it will still interact in the correct direction.

At this point I believe it has something to do with the different coordinate systems but I've been unable to isolate which part of my code is causing the problem. I've included my code below.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView){

let gestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handlePan:"))
self.view?.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: -2.0)
physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

let userShape = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
userShape.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, userShape.frame.size.height/2)
userShape.name = "userShape"
userShape.fillColor = SKColor.blueColor()


userShape.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))

userShape.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
userShape.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
userShape.physicsBody?.mass = 0.02
userShape.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0
userShape.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.5

addChild(userShape)
}
```

my handler

```
func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer!)
{

switch recognizer.state{
case .Began:
    var touchLocation = recognizer.locationInView(recognizer.view!)
    selectNodeForTouch(touchLocation)
case .Changed:
    var translation = recognizer.translationInView(recognizer.view!)
    translation = CGPointMake(translation.x, translation.y)
    self.panForTranslation(translation)
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: recognizer.view!)
case .Ended:
    var velocity = recognizer.velocityInView(recognizer.view)
    _selectedNode.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(velocity.x * velocityController, velocity.y * velocityController * -1.0))
default:
    break;

}

}
func panForTranslation(translation: CGPoint)
{
    var position = _selectedNode.position
    print(_selectedNode.position)
    _selectedNode.position = CGPointMake(position.x + translation.x, position.y - translation.y)
}
func selectNodeForTouch(touchLocation: CGPoint)//NODE SELECTOR
{
    var touchedNode = nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)
    _selectedNode = touchedNode

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out that it does have to do with some sort of conversation of coordinate systems. In handlePan within the .begin statement i placed this line directly after creating the touchLocation variable
"touchLocation = self.convertPointFromView(touchLocation)" and it seems to have fixed the problem.